# Using multiple images in imgArray

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm not experienced at all at coding. I'm currently developing a webapp. I hired programmers to do this for me, but I can't help to try a few things myself (just because I'm so curious). 
I work of an open source Audio app. The thing I'm trying to do is : for every music track that is being created, I want to have a different image as a mute button.

I now have this :

```
var imgArray = [];

var i=trackNumber;
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
{
     imgArray.push(new Image());
     imgArray[imgArray.length - 1].src = 'img/img' + i + '.png';
}

function show_image(src) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = imgArray[i];


    // This next line will just add it to the <body> tag
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}

// Render HTML


var span = document.createElement('tr');
span.innerHTML = '<td class="trackBox" style="height : ' + "120px;" + 'px">' +
    "<progress class='pisteProgress' id='progress" + trackNumber + "' value='0' max='100' style='width : " + SAMPLE_HEIGHT + "px' ></progress>" +
    instrument.name + '<div style="float : right;">' +
    "<button class='mute' id='mute" + trackNumber + "' onclick='muteUnmuteTrack(" + trackNumber + "<img src='imgArray[i]'" + "</button>" ; +
    "<button class='solo' id='solo" + trackNumber + "' onclick='soloNosoloTrack(" + trackNumber + ");'><img src='../img/noearphones.png' /></button></div>" +
    "<span id='volspan'><input type='range' class = 'volumeSlider custom' id='volume" + trackNumber + "' min='0' max = '100' value='100' oninput='setVolumeOfTrackDependingOnSliderValue(" + trackNumber + ");'/></span><td>"; 

divTrack.appendChild(span);
```

So every trackNumber should correspond with a different image. That's the idea. I made this work by doing something like `if (trackNumber == 0 )`  and then a whole new render HTML element for each track. But there should be a shortcut, right? With the code I have now no images show up at all.

Thank you so much for helping in advance. Again I'm sorry that I'm an absolute beginner in coding.

Comment: You have serious mistakes on the mute line.

Comment: Probably yeah.. so can you help me out?

Comment: I put an answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it now says syntax error : invalid or unexpected token..

Comment: That's another error. Can you paste the complete error and the line of code where you have that  error?

Comment: Sorry I fixed the syntax error. Now the image comes back as "undefined"

Comment: Yes, because you need to move the line `i = trackNumber` after the `for()´ statement. See my complete answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have serious concatenation mistakes on this line:

```
"<button class='mute' id='mute" + trackNumber + "' 
         onclick='muteUnmuteTrack(" + trackNumber + "<img src='imgArray[i]'" + "</button>" ; +
```

Change it with this:

```
"<button class='mute' id='mute" + trackNumber + "' 
         onclick='muteUnmuteTrack(" + trackNumber + ");'><img src='"+imgArray[i]+"'/></button>" ; +
```

And it will work.

### Edition:

The problem of the undefined image is because you are overriding `i` variable in the `for()` loop statement. You need to move that assignment to after the loop. The following is the complete code:

```
var imgArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
{
     imgArray.push('img/img' + i + '.png');
}

var i=trackNumber; // I move to this zone this line to avoid overriding

function show_image(src) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = imgArray[i];


    // This next line will just add it to the <body> tag
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}

// Render HTML

var span = document.createElement('tr');
span.innerHTML = '<td class="trackBox" style="height : ' + "120px;" + 'px">' +
    "<progress class='pisteProgress' id='progress" + trackNumber + "' value='0' max='100' style='width : " + SAMPLE_HEIGHT + "px' ></progress>" +
    instrument.name + '<div style="float : right;">' +
    "<button class='mute' id='mute" + trackNumber + "' onclick='muteUnmuteTrack(" + trackNumber + ");'><img src='"+imgArray[i]+"' /></button>" ; +
    "<button class='solo' id='solo" + trackNumber + "' onclick='soloNosoloTrack(" + trackNumber + ");'><img src='../img/noearphones.png' /></button></div>" +
    "<span id='volspan'><input type='range' class = 'volumeSlider custom' id='volume" + trackNumber + "' min='0' max = '100' value='100' oninput='setVolumeOfTrackDependingOnSliderValue(" + trackNumber + ");'/></span><td>"; 

divTrack.appendChild(span);
```

Comment: It now says in the console : [object%20HTMLImageElement] 404 (Not Found). Btw thank you so much for taking your time to help me!

Comment: Bad practise. First, in `for` loop, you should create an image object within source (src) before pushing to the array (not pushing first, then recalling it via index). Second, in line `span.innerHTML`, it's very very hard to read. How many elements exactly do you want to append?

Comment: That's the OP code, not mine, I only try to fix the error with the same code. If you feel fine put your own answer with your own code.

Comment: @patturik Ok, I edit the code, I remove the `new Image()` line on the array push, because you only need the reference of the src. Now the code must work.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Still comes back as "undefined"

Comment: @patturik The last edition. I change the array sets into the loop. Now you see a `push()` method. If this comes undefined is because the trackNumber is not on the array. Remember that you are constructing a loop with 5 images, with ids from zero (0) to four (4). A track number 5 will be undefined.

Comment: Sorry, goes from zero (0) to three (3)

Comment: Ha it works!! Amazing. Thank you so much @MarcosPérezGude. That's great. And thanks for explaining as well.

Comment: You are welcome, you can check this as the correct answer when it's available